# BibTeX: I couldn't open style file cj.bst : \bibstyle{cj : }

Tags: natbib

I'm using overleaf latex and want my bibliography to have the following style

[image: references]

I have searched for it, and I think I need to use the package **natbib** and **\bibliographystyle{cj}** (I'm not sure though).

However, the following error comes up

[image: error]

I don't know if I have to create a .bst file or if I'm missing something.
If I need to create a .bst file, I would appreciate that someone could tell me how to do it since I didn't find anything.

If there was an option available to use this style without making use of .bst, I would prefer that.

Comment: Your question does not appear to be related all that closely to the [natbib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) citation management package. Indeed, since numeric-style citation call-outs would appear to be employed, the [cite](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cite) package should do fine. What your query really comes down to is either finding an existing bibliography style (bst) file or creating a bst file from scratch. Your formatting requirements are somewhat uncommon -- nothing wrong with that. (... continued ... )

Comment: ( ... continued ... ) Two examples or slightly uncommon formatting choices: the use of `;` (semicolon) as the separator between authors, and the insertion of `:` (colon) immediately after the year in parentheses. If you can't find the file `cj.bst` (I, for one, can't locate it in TeXLive), you may want to look into running the `makebst` utility, which is part of the [custom-bib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib) package,  to create a bespoke bst file from scratch.